# Is it possible to design communication with WCF such that client doesn't need to know about concrete DTO that server uses to send over data?

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to create a design such that client only knows the interface of a class not the DTO.

In my application I have common interface that both client and server use:

```
public interface IBar
{
    bool Foo { get; set; }
}
```

On server side I implement this interface by a DTO:

```
public class BarDTO : IBar
{
    public bool Foo { get; set; }

    public BarDTO(IBar bar)
    {
        Foo = bar.Foo;
    }
}
```

On client side I have object that does some additional stuff:

```
public class BarClient : BindableBase, IBar
{
    public bool Foo 
    { 
        get => _foo; 
        set => SetProperty(ref _foo, value); 
    }

    public BarClient(IBar bar)
    {
        Foo = bar.Foo;
    }

    // some client-side stuff here
    // ...
}
```

My service contract:

```
public interface IWcfService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(BarDTO)]
    IBar ReturnBar();

    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(BarDTO)]
    void PassBar(IBar bar);

}
```

With ReturnBar() I have no issue because client doesn't need to care about concrete server object:

```
var bar = new ClientBar(_serviceClient.ReturnBar());
```

But I'm not sure how to send the data to server. When I try to:

```
_serviceClient.PassBar(new BarClient { Foo = true });
```

service enters faulted mode. I think in theory it should be possible because I tell WCF server side that IBar needs to be BarDTO. Client probably sends some xml looking like this (pseudocode):

```
<IBar>
    <Foo Type="bool" Value="true" />
</IBar>
```

Server have all information to create proper object.

Comment: that would depend on `PassBar` API of your wcf service.. is it casting recived `IBar` type to some concrete type, if yes and it is trying to cast it to some other type than `ClientBar` then it won't work.

Comment: Is it `ClientBar`, or `BarClient` that you are creating client-side? You show newing up `ClientBar` but you don't show if that implements `IBar`.